# Is it possible to access a Firebase hosting site via an IP address?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a hardcoded DDNS URL in an application that I can no longer modify the code for. It currently points to a server using its IP address and I'm trying to move over to Firebase.

My problem is that I need to update the DDNS URL with an *IP address* but I've only got a hosting URL like `https://myapp-123q4.firebaseapp.com/`.

My understanding is (from [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/eE6kAqDApU8/hgCcTIORCQAJ)) that because the entire system is shared, there are some specific IP addresses that can be used. Is there any way to access my own firebase hosting URL using an IP address?

(Pinging my firebase URL gave me the IP `151.101.1.195` which is one of the ones mentioned on the above linked post.)

Comment: Can the old app handle a 301 redirect?

Comment: @JamesPoag it can't :( the app gets the data from an DDNS URL from No-IP, which points to my old server's IP address. I have to keep the No-IP URL and can't change it :/ This was just going to be for a few months, so I guess I'll have to leave it as-is for a while. I was thinking a long-winded alternative was to buy a domain name, change the DDNS config to its IP address and redirect my domain to the firebase URL but I can't buy a domain either :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not depend on direct IP addresses for accessing Firebase Hosting.  There are simply not enough IPv4 addresses available for everyone to have exclusive access to one.  You need to use the host name in the HTTP request so that the server can route the request to the correct content.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that would be the answer :/ thanks for confirming :)